# Will this well enough to serve as a prerequisite to oksendal's book?

Tags: probability, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, finance, stochastic-integrals

Will this well enough to serve as a prerequisite to oksendal's stochastic differential equations: an introduction with applications book?

I refer to shiryeav's probability, but i guess it still miss out a lot of detail.

What other books can be a prerequisite too? (Gut's probability:A graduate course is a bit difficult for me (maybe because it is measure theory based?) and measure theory by Cohn book is too difficult for me)

Also, because i want this question to be meaningful, please also list out the prerequisite  topics that you know its going to be miss on the oksendal's book.

Comment: @MikeMiller - Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

partial answer here

1)Measure, Integral and Probability by Capinski

2)Probability Essentials by Jacods

3)Knowing the odds by Walsh

are all good but more elemetary than gut